# How to change sample rate for all files in a directory

Tags: bash, shell, sox

How do I change the sample rate for every file in the folder?

I have the following code and it just erases the files -- the file size becomes 0.

```
for i in wav/*.wav; do
    sox -r 8000 -e unsigned -b 16 -c 1 "$i" "$i"
done
```

Why is that?

Comment: Output to a temp file then mv the temp file in place of the original

Comment: Added the `sox` tag to your question. This looks to me more like a question how to use _sox_ properly than about how to do shell programming. You might consider removing the tags for _bash_ and _shell_ and posting this at [superuser](https://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 0):

`sox -r 8000 -e unsigned -b 16 -c 1 "$i" "$i"`

Your not using `$o` (the output file) anywhere - looks like you're trying to input and output from the same file (just a guess - not familiar with `sox`)

One approach would be to write to a temporary output file and then move that over the top of the input file:

```
for fname in wav/*.wav; do
    TMP_OUT=$(mktemp)
    sox -r 8000 -e unsigned -b 16 -c 1 "$fname" $TMP_OUT
    mv $TMP_OUT $fname
done
```

The danger here is that you lose the input file if something goes wrong. I would check the result of `sox` and only overwrite the input file if sox was successful.

Comment: Right! I forgot to remove that part, but that "$o" wouldn't do anything in the code

Comment: You are still using the same input and output file which is probably not going to work.

Comment: @John3136 : You are basically right. How to incorporate into your answer an example of how to set and use `o` in a meaningful way?